# Retrive data from view to controler CodeIgniter via href

Tags: codeigniter

Ok my code is in view file

```
echo '<h4>Lista podataka</h4>';
br().br();
$this->db->select('info');
$query = $this->db->get('pages');
foreach ($query->result() as $q){
    echo "<a href='update'>". $q->info  .br()."</a>";
```

}

with href i am calling controler

How to grab $q->info data to controler

Comment: If I am understanding you right, you want to pass the "$q->info" as a parameter to a function, within your controller? If so, read the user guide, it shows you how to pass uri segments; 

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're throwing mvc out of the window,  but basically :

example.com/controller/method/param